# When you build llvm from source, how do you install it to your system?

Tags: installation, cmake, clang, llvm, ninja

When reading through this:

https://www.llvm.org/docs/CMake.html

It tells you how to install to a target, but it doesn't tell you how to install to the system.

```
cmake --build . --target install
```

I am not sure what the target is in this case, nor how to properly configure it so it appears as a standard installation into my ubuntu system, insofar as it would be functionally the same as if I installed the development debian packages, and have it picked up by any other build looking to see if the libraries are installed.

Hence, how do I install all the projects under the llvm suite, from source, into Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command *will* install LLVM and all the configured projects (via LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS) to whatever location you specified in the first step with the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable.

If you did not set it, it takes on a platform-dependent value, most likely `/usr/local` on Linux. This is an appropriate place to put it. I would discourage you from trespassing on the package manager's territory. Untold misery is likely to result.

A "target" in CMake (and many other build systems) is just "something that must be done". Usually it's "compile something to a file with a corresponding name", but it can also be "run an installation script". CMake creates an `install` target for that purpose in *every* project. It's also a popular convention in Make/autotools based build systems.

Comment: I'm fine with it in `/usr/local` so does that mean I just need to run `cmake --build . --target install` ? I did once already but it was painfully slow and failed at around `~[3000]`

Comment: That is the command you need to run, yes. That target depends on all the other targets, so it is apparently failing to build LLVM as part of its first step. You should open a new question with the error message if you need help getting LLVM to build.

Comment: And yes, LLVM is an enormous project. It takes 20 minutes to build on my 10-core workstation.

Comment: Hey thank you so much. You were a lot of help.